# What flows in a general circuit?

Tags: theory

I've been learning electronics and have noticed there are pretty much only 2 ways people refer to what flows through the wires; electrons or charge.

I get that electrons are a type of charge but not necessarily vice versa, so as per my question:

Do other sub-atomic particles also flow when there's a voltage?

Comment: What flows through the wires is **current** in 99.9% of all scenarios in electrical engineering.

Comment: Electrons are not a type of charge; they are a charge carrier, they have charge, but they are not the charge. Just like you are not a type of name, but you have a name.

Comment: First off, Andy, thanks but that's like saying what flows through the water is fluid.

Comment: Lol I meant to make that comment longer... Also is there a way I can just reply to your reply? Anyway, Hearth, yeah thanks for the correction. It's good to break habits like that early.

Comment: @Wilhelm If you want people to see your comments, you need to put an @ before their name; that will give them a notification. I only happened to see this one by chance.

Comment: And what Andy is saying is in fact true; current, being the time-derivative of charge, is what flows through wires. It's no different from talking about how currents flow in the ocean, except that here we're talking about a current of charge, not of mass. Charge is the medium of that current, but it can take many forms, from something as small as individual electrons to as large as ionized gas molecules in a gas discharge tube. No particles are even necessary; current (as ∂D/∂t) flows even between the plates of a vacuum capacitor.

Comment: The question of what flows in the current is relevant. I understand that what flows is energy carried by the electromagnetic field produced by the moving charges. A charge has an electric field, but a moving charge produces an electromagnetic field that transfers the energy. It doesn't matter if the charges move in one direction, or back and forward all the time, the energy flows forward, in one direction, and passes capacitors, transformers or empy space.  But for electronics it doesn't help much, is better to think in terms of current.

Comment: @Hearth Ah! I see I didn't know the definition of current... sorry Andy! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

The flow of charge is current.

Current is what charges capacitors, causes a voltage drop across resistors, and creates a magnetic field around the path where the current is flowing.

It's sufficient when dealing with ideal circuit theory to do electronic design, and use Norton and Thevenin rules, to simply say current. You never need to go down a level to see what's underneath that. 'Current' will let you design linear circuits, digital circuits, RF communications, computers, basically everything covered by the general term 'electronic engineering'.

If for some reason you do need to move outside ideal circuit theory and find out about the nitty-gritty of charge carriers, perhaps you're doing electrolysis, or plasma physics, or designing new semiconductor materials, or building particle accelerators, then you start to worry about ions with various charges, electrons, holes (a quantum mechanical particle just as 'real' as an electron), protons.

A lot of people, especially those just starting out, get fixated on trying to understand electrons. Electrons are not necessary, to do electronic design. Classical models of electrons are not sufficient to understand conduction in metals or semi-conductors, and who wants to learn quantum mechanics at the start of their electronic career?

Comment: Holes are not just as 'real' as electrons. Electrons are electrons even in solid matter. Holes or "heavy fermions" etc. are quasiparticles (electrons that interact strongly with the lattice and each other).

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about tobalt... But thanks Neil. I am (as you realise) getting fixated on understanding the nitty gritty. I've previously done a maths degree, so I like understanding to a comfortable level, hence me wanting to understand this is just so I can not have it annoy me when soldering up circuits :)

Comment: @Wilhelm fully understanding the mechanisms of current flow involves an education in quantum physics, and taking fields and waves classes as well as device physics.  Asking for a complete, easily digestible answer is like asking for a complete, easily digestible explanation of gradient descent for someone who got as far as algebra 2.

Comment: @mapplejacks I didn't ask for a "complete, easily digestible explanation" though... I just wanted some discussion

Answer (score 1):

What flows in a circuit is 'current', but in a general sense, not just electrons moving around.

For example, if you create a circuit with an AC source, a lightbulb and a capacitor in series, the lightbulb will light, but the electrons will not pass through the capacitor. They will not flow around all the circuit. But the energy will indeed arrive to the lightbulb.

The 'conventional' DC current will not go through the capacitor neither. But the displacement current, defined by Maxwell, will flow across the capacitor.
So anyway we can think in current flowing.

Also, electrons don't move at light speed in wires, they go much slower or just vibrate. Are the electromagetic field waves along the current what goes at light speed.

Comment: Thanks Gos! Why won't DC current go through the capacitor?

Comment: A capacitor has two plates separated by a dielectric, a non conducting material. So they are not in contact, it's like a disconnected circuit for DC. Electrons or 'DC current' will not pass from one side to the other.  But they are very close and their electric field influences the other side.

Answer (score -1):

> > Do other sub-atomic particles also flow when there's a voltage?

Sub-atomic particles are too tight to the nucleus and I doubt that they can freely move.

---

Science in 2023 says that only electrons can move from one atom to the other

---

Electrons are particles with mass and charge.

Electrons' charge was defined as to be Negative by scientists.

I've never heard of particles with charge but without mass.

In electronic books they use both "moving charge" and "electrons" interchangeably.

When a certain number of electrons going/moving/traveling in the same direction scientists say that we are in presence of an electrical current.

Electronics deals with electrons moving in wires, in semiconductors or in a dielectric materials.

---

Electrons have also a spin and other observable properties but, at your level, mass and charge are enough to learn electronics.

Comment: Ions are also "particles with mass and charge", and you'll find plenty of them flowing through the electrolyte of components like lead-acid batteries and electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: Ions in lead-acid batterie are "molecules" with mass and charge

Comment: Think of displacement current. This really is ions as well as electrons.

Comment: Displacement current is a term in the Maxwell equations.
That term is dominant inside the dielectric material of capacitors and negligible inside conductors. This term is proportional to the amplitude of on AC electric field that displaces and creates oscillating dipoles in dielectric materials.

Comment: @EnricoMigliore A molecule is still a type of particle, just a very large one. And ions don't have to be molecules; they can be as simple as a single proton, H⁺.

Comment: All good stuff to think about guys!